# C# PLINQ .AsParallel() position in query

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing

StackOverflow,

Within C# PLINQ I understand the position of ".AsParallel()" impacts how the query is run.  For example, where ".AsParallel()" occurs in the middle of a query it will execute sequentially before the method and parallel after the method. ([PLINQ: Parallel Queries in .NET](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/plinq-parallel-queries-in-net/232600819?pgno=3)).

My question is, with a more complex query (below), where ".AsParallel" occurs at the start of the query (as a prefix to .Select) will all following methods execute parallel also?  (currently, ".AsParallel" occurs after the .Select).

```
  Collection =
   typeof (Detail).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
     .SelectMany(propertyInfo => recentPhases
      .Where(phase => phase.Finalised)
      .SelectMany(phase => phase.PhaseDetail
      .Select(keyValuePair => new
     {
      phase.Direction,
      phase.Momentum,
      keyValuePair.Key,
      keyValuePair.Value
     }))
     .Select(arg => new
     {
      Key = new BmkKey
      {
       Direction = (arg.Direction == Dir.Up ? Dir.Up : Dir.Down),
       Momentum = (arg.Momentum == Mom.Price ? Mom.Price : Mom.Time),
       BarNumber = arg.Key,
       DetailType = propertyInfo.Name
      },
      Value = (double) propertyInfo.GetValue(arg.Value, null)
     }))
    .AsParallel().GroupBy(grp => grp.Key)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => new Distribution(grp.Select(x => x.Value)));
```

Comment: Btw, `GetProperties` is the expensive part of this query, so it doesn't make sense to parallelize grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes everything will be executed parallel after the `AsParallel()` method is called. From [msdn:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413602(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
public static ParallelQuery<TSource> AsParallel<TSource>(
this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

So the input is an `IEnumerable<T>` and the output a `ParallelQuery<T>`.

If we then look at the [ParallelEnumerable class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Provides a set of methods for querying objects that implement ParallelQuery{TSource}. This is the parallel equivalent of Enumerable.

So from then on, you won't be calling the methods defined for `IEnumerable<T>` but you will be calling their parallel counterparts defined for `ParallelEnumerable`.